# Regular expression struggle

Tags: shell

These are my files

```
SO_8543_IP_3_ablt_R1.fq.gz
SO_8543_IP_4_ablt_R1.fq.gz
SO_8543_INPUT_1_ablt_R1.fq.gz  SO_8543_IP_5_ablt_R1.fq.gz
SO_8543_INPUT_2_ablt_R1.fq.gz  SO_8543_IP_6_ablt_R1.fq.gz
SO_8543_INPUT_3_ablt_R1.fq.gz  SO_8543_IP_7_ablt_R1.fq.gz
SO_8543_INPUT_4_ablt_R1.fq.gz  SO_8543_IP_8_ablt_R1.fq.gz
SO_8543_IP_1_ablt_R1.fq.gz     
SO_8543_IP_2_ablt_R1.fq.gz
```

Im running the below line

```
for i in $(ls *.fq*.gz | cut -f1-5 -d"_" | uniq);do echo $i; done

bowtie2 -q -p20 -x /run/media/punit/data1/BowtieIndex/hg38  -1 ${i}_R1.fq.gz | samtools view -bS - >${i%}.bam;

done
```

So if i use run this

```
for i in $(ls *.fq*.gz | cut -f1-5 -d"_" | uniq);do echo $i; done
```

I get files as such

```
SO_8543_INPUT_1_ablt
SO_8543_INPUT_2_ablt
SO_8543_INPUT_3_ablt
SO_8543_INPUT_4_ablt
SO_8543_IP_1_ablt
SO_8543_IP_2_ablt
SO_8543_IP_3_ablt
SO_8543_IP_4_ablt
SO_8543_IP_5_ablt
SO_8543_IP_6_ablt
SO_8543_IP_7_ablt
SO_8543_IP_8_ablt
```

The part of the file name that is consistent is `_R1.fq.gz` which goes after the input argument. As these are single end files so only 1 im giving one end as input.

Error message

```
***
Error: Must specify at least one read input with -U/-1/-2
(ERR): bowtie2-align exited with value 1
./Chip_SEQ.sh: line 25: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
./Chip_SEQ.sh: line 25: `done'
```

it looks like its not able to recognize as input .Any help or suggestion would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have an extra `done`, instead you want:

```
for i in $(ls *.fq*.gz | cut -f1-5 -d"_" | uniq); do
    echo $i
    bowtie2 -q -p20 -x /run/media/punit/data1/BowtieIndex/hg38 -1 ${i}_R1.fq.gz | samtools view -bS - >${i}.bam
done
```

As an aside, I'm not a big fan of piping `ls` to cut and then uniq. Why not instead:

```
for f in *.fq.gz; do
    sampleName=${f%%_R1.fq.gz}
    echo $sampleName
    bowtie2 -q ...
done
```

That will do the same thing, but (A) it's clearer what's going on and (B) it can be reused if your sample names change. Also, stop writing bash scripts and use snakemake or something like that instead, it scales much better and is less error-prone.

Comment: now after looking at my script number of times i figured out the "done" is extra .let me try your code. My shell scripting is very rudimentary so i use which i know is safe to save my self from screwing up .

Comment: i ran your first code the but i still get this error "Error: Must specify at least one read input with -U/-1/-2 (ERR): bowtie2-align exited with value 1" its  not able to recognize the input file, not sure what's wrong .

Comment: Try `-U` instead of `-1` in the bowtie2 command.

Comment: yes that was the mistake i was doing thank you very much

Comment: @krushnachChandra please read [this link](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) to understand why you should basically _never_ try to parse the output of `ls`.

Comment: @terdon I'd not say "never parse ls", I'd say "Don't parse ls unless you know exactly what you're doing, especially the filenames involved". I do a lot of `for f in $(/bin/ls -1 <glob> | downstream_operations)` because I'm 100% certain that each value of `$f` plays well with the other parts in the code.

Comment: @RamRS well, parsing ls is asking for trouble and just unnecessary. `for f in <glob>` does exactly the same thing but without calling an external process and without running any risk of failure because of file names. So why use a riskier and less efficient approach when it doesn't provide any benefit at all?

Comment: It's really useful when the `$()` feeding the loop involves a `uniq`, for example. It can't always be avoided. Whenever possible, use a glob. But don't have a hard constraint against `$(/bin/ls | downstream_stuff)`

Comment: thats a life saver link